# Externalizing configuration for Hibernate Search

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am running hibernate search with spring boot. I have written a working configuration for my application. How ever, i want to externalize my configuration and use `./config/hibernate.properties` instead of `src/main/resources/hibernate.properties`. After copying my properties file to the desired location, i am getting and exception:

```
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Anyone with any idea on how i should tell spring to read my configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it seems hibernate-search will prevent application from starting as long as a `hibernate.properties` configuration file does not exist. After trying for a while without success, i found a work around for my problem.

- First, i created an empty `hibernate.properties` file and place it under `src/main/resources`.
- Secondly, i moved  all hibernate-search configurations to `application.properties` as follows:

  `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexmanager = elasticsearch`
   `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host = http://my-server.com`
   `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy = CREATE`
  `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status = yellow`

This way, the application will start and spring will get all configuration from the externalized configuration as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: Hibernate Search does not rely on `hibernate.properties` directly, especially if it's empty. In fact we have a demo that uses Spring Boot and it works with just an `application.yaml`: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-demos/tree/7e69352e7eb28374fef939f731dba29f7da104a0/hibernate-search/hsearch-elasticsearch-wikipedia/src/main/resources . Maybe you could try removing the `hibernate.properties` file now that you added the configuration in `application.properties`?

Answer (score 0):

Move your configuration to an `src/main/resources/application.properties` file and prepend `spring.jpa.properties.` everywhere, so `hibernate.dialect` will become `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`, for example.

Then you can use Spring features to move your configuration wherever you want. To move it to `./config/application.properties` I suppose you will have to add `@PropertySource("./config/application.properties")` to one of your `@Configuration` classes, or something similar.

I'm sure you can also keep the hibernate configuration in a separate file (separate from the rest of your application configuration).

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html for more details about externalizing configuration in Spring Boot.

Comment: The issue i am having is purely with hibernate-search. Spring boot configs are working just fine. Remember i was externalizing the configs so again i cannot use the `src/main/resources/application.properties` directory

Comment: I only mentioned `src/main/resources/application.properties` as a first step; as I mentioned, you can externalize `application.properties` using `@PropertySource("./config/application.properties")`